WeakReferenceMessenger doesn't register first message
I am using WeakReferenceMessenger in order to send a message while tapping a Button. The problem is that the first message is sent, but does never get registered. Since the 2nd tap of the Button everything works fine.
Here is my code:
SenderClass.xaml.cs:
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Messaging;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Messaging.Messages;

namespace MyApp;

public partial class SenderClass : ContentPage
{
    public SenderClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();  
    }

    public class SendString : ValueChangedMessage<string>
    {
        public SendString(string value) : base(value) { }
    }

    private async void OnButtonTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new SendString("A random string"));
    }
}

ReceiverClass.xaml.cs:
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Messaging;

namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class ReceiverClass : ContentPage
    {
        public ReeceiverClass()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<SenderClass.SendString>(this, (r, m) =>
            {
                OnStringReceived(m.Value);
            });            
        }

        sting receivedMessage;

        private void OnStringReceived(string myString)
        {
            receivedMessage = "Received message is:" + myString;
        }
    }
}

Using break points I can see that WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new SendString("A random string")); in SenderClass always gets executed even when the Button is tapped for the first time, but OnStringReceived(m.Value); line of code in the constructor of the ReceiverClass does not get executed when the Button is tapped for the first time. Since the 2nd tap everuthing works as expected.
So what's the deal and how can the issue get solved?

Have you tried using the IRecipient interface instead and see if that works better?

No, I haven't. I may have a look and give it a try. Yet, I would like to find out what is causing that weird behavior with WeakReferenceMessenger. Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Please ensure that your ReceiverClass is created before you send the first message.

@LukaszSzczygielek Yes, that's something I was thinking of. But how can it be done? ReceiverClass is a Page which I open when the message is sent. Can I create it and keep it in the background?

So what you are saying is you want to create the Subscriber after you Publish the message?

@FreakyAli
I have tried navigating to the Page by using await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//ReceiverClass", true); both before and after calling WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new SendString("A random string")); It didn't make any difference. Both orders resulted exactly in the same behavior.

If you want to make it your way:

Make Singleton MessageQueueService
SenderClass calls MessageQueueService.Add(message), and Broadcasts WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new YouHaveMessage()).
ReceiverClass, after initialization, checks MessageQueueService for old messages, and handles them. And registers for new messages WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<SenderClass.YouHaveMessage>

Actually how you pass data:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-8.0#pass-data
Edit:
Using a "global variable", as you suggest will also work.
And yes, performance wise it is better. But remember, than navigation happens relatively rare, and you should not even consider optimization in that area.
Your main goal should be to keep your code as clean as possible, for as long as possible. Sharing the memory where you save one string seems perfectly fine now. But when the project grows (more navigation paths, more threads, more data to be passed around) it becomes hard to watch who is modifying this shared memory and when.

How bad would it be to define a public class with a public static field that would act as "global" variable? Performance wise, probably it would be better, even just a little, if not much, than using any type of messaging.

@Costas I edited my answer, I still suggest that you pass the data , with the navigation code.

Well, what I'm trying to achieve is to pass the same value to multiple tabs.
From a logical point of view, using a common variable that every Page that needs that specific data will have access seems reasonable.
To be honest it seems more counterproductive to use multiple lines of code for what it can be achieved with a single line, except if there are other downsides.

@Costas those lines enforce patterns, architecture and code organization. The time you will save now, you will pay in magnitudes later. I was unfortunate to have to work on 30 years old, bug infested, multithreaded, c/c++ applications. Nobody can be explained how important the code organization is, before they get themselves into such mess.
